# How To Save ListView Data across Sessions?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

**INTRO:**

At at the risk of getting the question closed, I will attempt to ask it anyway. I did search a lot but most are about saving the `ListView` state during orientation changes and restoring when coming back to the `Activity`. And that is not what I am looking for.

Applications such as the Twitter app and several others like it will come back to the same state it was at when you last used the app. When you return to the app, any new data, if available loads above the current position.

In my current setup, I make use of three classes.

1. `public class NewNotifications extends SherlockFragment {....} // THE FRAGMENT WHERE THE DATA IS PROCESSED`
2. `public class NewNotificationsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {....} // THE ADAPTER FOR THE CUSTOM LISTVIEW`
3. `public class NotificationsData {} // A HELPER SETTER / GETTER CLASS`

All the data displayed currently is fetched live using the Facebook SDK and everything works just fine. But I am concerned for the tremendous data usage that occurs. For instance, the above three classes work in conjunction to show any new / old notifications for the current logged in user. But every time the user clicks on the *Notifications* button, the same data is fetched all over again regardless of their being new notifications. This brings me to the primary question.

**THE QUESTION:**

The primary question is, how do apps such as Twitter store the exact position in the `ListView` regardless of what the device is doing? I can have restarted the phone 20 times and still come back to the same state.

Clearly, the data is being stored somewhere. Do they store them in a `Database` or a `SharedPreference` file? *I am inclined to think `Database`.* But I would love to know any other alternatives. I am, naturally, also inclined to think that storing the received data while still processing it (*in the Fragment*) would be the best possible alternative.

*Are their any libraries out there that do this task which my Google foo could not find? Or will I have to create the logic for such a task all by myself?* Regardless of the suggestion to this effect, I am open to every suggestion. I am not looking for a lazy ready made solution. I merely seek suggestions / directions. :-)

I am sorry for the state of the question which is mighty subjective and is most likely going to be closed.

Comment: you need to save all states etc. into an DB to restore your app state, regardless whats happening on your device

Comment: @Nickolaus: Hmmm... So I was thinking on the right path. Any idea for how long these apps hold the data in them?

Comment: look at the Activity lifecycle, it is always the same, therefore these apps must store their state in a DB or through external files

Comment: @Nickolaus: Could you post your suggestion as an answer? Since this was the only suggestion made here and a correct one at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save data which from your application, that you want to restore in your app, whatever the apps lifecycle is doing, you will need to save the data indepenedently either in an internal DB or on the internal/external device storage.